# Xcode 5 crashes on startup

Tags: xcode, macos

suddenly I can't launch an Xcode app anymore. Xcode basically crashes on startup with the following message:

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: IDEContainer - uniquing lock

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A3005
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-3542/Framework/Classes/MacroExpansion/DVTMacroDefinitionConditionSet.mm:153
Details:  stringRep should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty string
Object:   <DVTMacroDefinitionConditionSet>
Method:   +conditionSetFromStringRepresentation:getBaseMacroName:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe8784155a0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
```

I can however create new apps, cannot open any old apps though.

I tried disabling version control but it didn't help.

Tried deleting and installing Xcode, downgrading from 5.1 to 5.0.2 - no luck

**UPDATE**

There is something really strange about it - I move the project to a different folder (Dropbox) and I can actually open it.. I guess it is some kind of path issue, but I am not using any absolute paths.

Comment: https://bugreport.apple.com/‎

Comment: and? I reported the bug Xcode still crashes

Comment: Try deleting the contents of your derived data directory

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Solution / Work-around

1. Start Xcode without loading any opened projects (hold <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>)
2. Uncheck Source Control in Preferences
3. Hope for a fix from Apple

The bug seems to be related to Source Control, so I would recommend leaving it off for the time being.

Comment: source control disabled. The strange thing is although I wipe the Derived data folder (and even reinstall Xcode it still remembers about that single project that I can't open). Does Xcode store some kind of history/cache somewhere else??

Comment: Usually it's just in the derived data, although depending on your source control setup it could be loading it from elsewhere. Try doing a `find` *nameofproject* from Terminal perhaps. Which version of OSX are you running? Also, does your project use a self-signed certificate; the crash could be related specifically to that.

Comment: Mavericks could be caching the preferences, which would only add to your frustration. In terminal try `defaults read ~/library/preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist` after turning off the Source Control and quitting XCode.

Comment: ok, so it does show the contents I guess. What can I do about it? remove that file? or try to clear it? -- Edit - just removed the file but still same story